# How to recover with a retry from gremlin NoHostAvailableException

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I am using Gremlin Java driver to connect to a local gremlin server.

Simple code flow

**Creating client**

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.build().addContactPoint(<endp>).port(<port>).enableSsl(false).create()
Client client = cluster.connect();
```

**Submit Script**

```
client.submit("g.V().count()");
```

If when i submit the first time the Gremlin server is down, on subsequent retries after bringing back gremlin server, connection still fails to create.

Exception First attempt when Gremlin Server is down:

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason
```

Exception After Gremlin server is brought back up:

```
tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions
```

One thing to note is i do not create client on retry just do
**Submit Script**

```
client.submit("g.V().count()");
```

It is quite possible that Gremlin server may go down anytime, how to recover in such circumstances. Fundamentally is

> NoHostAvailableExceptio

recoverable?

Comment: It turns out that if i create a client in retry it works, not sure what the best practice is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the `Client` should attempt to reconnect to a host that is previously marked unavailable. By default, it should be retrying the host at 1 second intervals as governed by this configuration: `connectionPool.reconnectInterval`. In your case, however I think you've uncovered a bug where the reconnect attempts are not started because the `Client` was never able to reach the host in the first place. As of 3.4.11, you can only remedy this by recreating the `Client` as you noted in your comments. I've created an issue to track this problem here: [TINKERPOP-2569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2569)

Comment: Thank you, I see that a fix is pushed, for now, will recreate Clent.